# sending ssl certificate ".cer" file with PHP cURL

Tags: php, ssl-certificate

I'm stuck for hours now I'm trying to send cURL request with ssl certificate ".cer" file and I found these settings for cURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  getcwd().'/cert/ca.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd().'/cert/mycert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'password');
```

now the problem is I only have this '/cert/ca.crt' file and I don't have the .pem one nor the password? do I have to set the last two options?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I get 
```array(3) {
  ["httpcode"]=>
  int(0)
  ["data"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["hasError"]=>
  int(28)
}```

Comment: ca.cert is from the certificate authority. To obtain your own certficate you'll have to order it from the authority via CSR. During the creation of the request, a private key is created.. and once the authority has signed your request, you receive your certificate.

Comment: I hope you have the correct certs & keys from the CA authority..

Comment: @LarsStegelitz they sent me this ".cer" file and told me to install it in my server. I Guess it's only possible in ASP.net but in PHP it's a different story. so how to request it from the API owners whom gave me the certificate file?

Comment: @sid they just sent me this file. what should I ask for since I work with PHP?

Comment: `getcwd()` is the current working directory ...you probably don't want to have this file anywhere below the web-root, so this might apply for CLI only, but not for SAPI. Besides, it is entirely unclear what the question even is. If they've sent you the file, why you don't have it then??

Comment: Fact is: if do not have a private key already, the certificate isn't "yours". you'll have to own the private key. if you order a certicate from a trusted provider, you'd have to do that via CSR, and you'd need a privte key to create this CSR.

Comment: @MartinZeitler  yes I have the file and I set it as CURLOPT_CAINFO option but I'm asking is that the write way to do it? what are the .pem file and password? should I told the API owner to send them to me? note: API owner is a gov institution